# Excel: Make formula dynamic by changing the column in formula

Tags: excel, matrix

hope someone can help me.
I have 10 12x1 matrices and each is used along with another 12x1 matrix to calculate the Euclidean distance for each respective matrix. From those 10 Euclidean distances calculated I find the minimum value which is situated in columns M-V. I then work out the variance vectors of that matrix (corresponding with the min Euclidean distance) to form a new 11x1 matrix.

How do I change the column in the formula for variance vectors, seeing that the minimum value constantly changes from column M through to V?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muc0G.jpg)

I already have a way to return the column name

Answer (score 0):

paste this formula in cell `L2`.

`=INDEX(M2:V3,2,MATCH(MIN(M2:V2),M2:V2,0))-MIN(M2:V2)`

Comment: It returns 9.91667? All that I want (if you look at the picture attached) is to change (=O3-O2) to lets say (=S3-S2) if the Euclidean minimum is at column S

Comment: It does not work when the Euclidean minimum changes to another column

Comment: change column `R` to column `V` in formula